# How to Respond a Multi-disciplinary question to make it relevant to Bioacoustics?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, moderation, moderators

Bioacoustics is fundamentally multi-disciplinary and many questions relevant to this field can also be appropriate for other Stack Exchange sites. Our community (will) identify guidelines for asking good cross-discipline questions ([see this post](https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132/how-to-ask-a-multidisciplinary-question-on-bioacoustics-stack-exchange)). Separate from how to write a good question is how to respond to questions that need help (do not meet these guidelines).

**What steps should our community/moderators take when someone asks a multi-disciplinary question that does not adequately fit the guidelines we develop?**

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways that community members can respond to multi-disciplinary questions to ensure that they are appropriate for the Bioacoustics Stack Exchange, and that they adequately fit the guidelines we have developed (see [this post](https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132/how-to-ask-a-multidisciplinary-question-on-bioacoustics-stack-exchange) for guidelines). As always, we should expect responses to follow the SE ‘be kind’ policy outlined in their [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct).

**USE YOUR VOTES**

Votes are a way to express value and agreement/disagreement.

- ***Vote up:*** You think this is a good question and is useful to the site
- ***Vote Down:*** You think the question is off-topic, inappropriate, or needs help. Please consider adding a comment if you think the post
  can be improved.

**REQUEST IMPROVEMENTS**

Community members can provide a **general comment** on posts to request that they read the guidelines (here) and improve their post so that it meets those guidelines.  For example:

> Thank you for your question! This multi-disciplinary question can also
> apply to other SE sites. Please use these guidelines to edit your
> question to fit our expectations for the Bioacoustics site
> ([How to ask a multidisciplinary question on Bioacoustics Stack Exchange?](https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132/how-to-ask-a-multidisciplinary-question-on-bioacoustics-stack-exchange))

Community members can also provide **comments requesting specific edits** or refinements to improve a question/title to better fit our expectations for a relevant cross-disciplinary question.

If there is strong community interest in the question but the Original Poster does not improve the question within a few days/week, **the question may be edited by one of an interested community member so that it meets community expectations.**

**CLOSE VOTE**

If there is insufficient community interest and the Original Poster does not improve the question so that it meets the expectations outlined in the guidelines, members can vote to close the question. Questions can be re-opened if there is sufficient community interest or the question or the question

*[Note, this is a drafty draft and I encourage suggestions to improve! Alternative approaches may be posted as separate answers]*